# Distance from a point to a plane (in the parametric form not general form)

Tags: linear-algebra, plane-geometry

I have a point $Q = [7 2 1]$ and I need to find the distance to the plane $P = [1 2 0] + s[1 -1 1] + t[1 0 3]$. I'm not sure how to approach this question.I know to do this question if the equation of the plane was given in the form $Ax + By + Cz = D$ but I'm not sure how to do it in this form
I have thought of two methods but I'm not sure which is correct.
[This is the first method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TebZn.jpg)[and this is the second method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCi0X.png)

Could someone please advise me if either method is correct and if not the correct method.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

The $Ax+By+Cz+D$ approach is correct, here's another one:
Let $Q=(7,2,0)^T$, $P=a+sv_1+tv_2$ where $a=(1,2,0)^T$, $v_1=(1,−1,1)^T$, $v_2=(1,0,3)^T$ then we find minimal distance $|PQ|=\sqrt{(Q-P)^2}$ over all possible values of $s,\,t$ as *the* distance.
Let's rearrange things a bit first, find $v_2'=v_2+uv_1$ such that $v_2'.v_1=0$: $(v_2+uv_1).v_1=0\Leftrightarrow$ $v_2.v_1+uv_1.v_1=0\Rightarrow$ $u=-\frac{v_2.v_1}{v_1.v_1}\Leftrightarrow$ $v_2'=v_2-\frac{v_2.v_1}{v_1.v_1}v_1$.
Let's say now $sv_1+tv_2=sv_1+t(v_2'-uv_1)=(s-tu)v_1+tv_2'=s'v_1+tv_2'$ then $(P-Q)^2=$ $(a-Q+s'v_1+tv_2')^2=$ $(a-Q)^2+s'\cdot(2(a-Q).v_1)+t(2(a-Q).v_2')+{s'}^2v_1^2+t^2{v_2'}^2$ it's obvious that $(P-Q)^2$ have the minimal value when $s'=-\frac{(a-Q).v_1}{v_1^2}$, $t=-\frac{(a-Q).v_2'}{{v_2'}^2}$, hence the desired result.

And another possible approach is finding such $s,\,t$ that $(P-Q).v_i=0$ for $i=1,2$: $$\begin{cases}
(a-Q+sv_1+tv_2)v_1=0\\
(a-Q+sv_1+tv_2)v_2=0
\end{cases}$$ $$\begin{cases}
(a-Q).v_1+sv_1^2+tv_2.v_1=0\\
(a-Q).v_2+sv_1.v_2+tv_2^2=0
\end{cases}$$ is linear w.r.t. $s,\,t$ so hence finding $s,\,t$ we find $|PQ|$ as the desired distance.

However, these two approaches are useful when one can't take $v_1\times v_2$ cross product, e.g. working in $4$ or more dimentions.

Answer (score 0):

A point in the plane is $(1,2,0)$ and a vector normal to the plane is

\begin{align*}(1,-1,1) \times (1,0,3) & = (-3,-2,1).
\end{align*}

So the equation of the plane is $$-3(x-1) -2(y-2) +z = 0$$ which simplifies to $$3x +2y - z = 7.$$ You can take it from here. Edit: both of your methods are equivalent, but you made a mistake in the second attempt.